# Assembly 16 bit illogical mistake (?)

Tags: assembly, x86-16, 16-bit

I don't understand why this code print me the char I've insert back and the alphabet string if nobody told him to do it...

```
.model
.stack 100h
.data

lettere DB 10 DUP(?)
frase1 DB 10,13,"inserisci 10 caratteri$"
frase2 DB ">>$"
caporiga DB 10,13,"$"
counter DB 0
char DB ?

alpha DB "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz$"

.code
.startup

  lea dx,frase1
  mov ah,09h
  int 21h

  lea dx,caporiga
  mov ah,09h
  int 21h

insertLoop:

  inc counter

  lea dx,counter
  mov ah,02h
  int 21h

  lea dx,frase2
  mov ah,09h
  int 21h

  mov ah,01h
  int 21h
  mov lettere+(counter-1),al

  lea dx,caporiga
  mov ah,09h
  int 21h

  cmp counter,10
  JB insertLoop

  mov ah,4ch
  int 21h
end
```

Comment: Could you please phrase this in a better way? I'm having trouble understanding your question. Also please make sure to place your code in between triple backticks like so: \`\`\`code\`\`\`

Comment: `char` is just before the alphabet, and I'm guessing you are printing using `09h` which expects `$` at the end. Your `char` has only the characters and misses that and it just goes over printing the alphabet until it find `$` at the end of it.

Comment: I'm surprised `mov lettere+(counter-1),al` assembles at all.  It definitely can't use the `db` at `counter` as an index for your array; probably it's just adding the two addresses together if your assembler doesn't reject that as being nonsense like it should.  Use a debugger to single-step, and look at disassembly of the resulting machine code.

Comment: To index memory, you need the index in a register (BX, SI, or DI), like `[lettere + SI]`.  Use registers for this, not memory, that's what they're for.

Comment: _"if your assembler doesn't reject that as being nonsense like it should"_ In MASM syntax brackets are sometimes optional, so that instruction ought to be equivalent to `mov [lettere+counter-1],al`. I don't see why the assembler should reject that, unless maybe if the address calculation overflows.

Comment: @Michael: When does it ever make sense to add the addresses of two symbols?  Maybe if you've defined one of them with an `equ` or something instead of a real address?  Interestingly, NASM *does* accept `mov eax, foo+bar` (as a mov-immediate with just offsets relative to the start of the file or section, not absolute addresses: https://godbolt.org/z/zsGxxYnhY), but `mov eax, [foo+bar]` is rejected with "invalid effective address: impossible segment base multiplier", when assembling into an ELF object of flat binary.  YASM rejects even the immediate.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't understand **why** this code print me the char I've insert back and the alphabet string if nobody told him to do it...

The `mov lettere+(counter-1),al` instruction does not do what you want.
MASM will add the (offset)addresses of *lettere* (0) and *counter* (41), and then subtract 1, yielding the address 40 where the instruction then overwrites an important **$** string terminator. The next time that your program tries to print a newline *caporiga*, the DOS.PrintString function 09h will continue printing characters until it finds the **$** that ends your alphabet string.

---

> ```
> lea dx,counter
> mov ah,02h
> int 21h
> ```

This is another error. The DOS.PrintCharacter function 02h expects to find a **character** in the `DL` register, but this `lea dx,counter` instruction clearly loads an address.

```
mov  dl, counter
add  dl, '0'
mov  ah, 02h
int  21h
```

The correct code first retrieves the count [1,10] from memory and then adds '0' (48) in order to convert into a printable character. This will of course fail when your count is 10. Look in [Displaying numbers with DOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45904075/displaying-numbers-with-dos) to learn how to overcome this problem.

---

One possible solution:

```
...

  xor BX, BX        ; Reset counter
insertLoop:
  inc BX            ; Increment counter
  lea dx, [BX + 48] ; -> DL = "1", "2", ...
  mov ah, 02h       ; Won't work when counter is 10
  int 21h

  lea dx, frase2
  mov ah, 09h
  int 21h

  mov ah, 01h
  int 21h
  mov [lettere + BX - 1], al

  lea dx, caporiga
  mov ah, 09h
  int 21h

  cmp BX, 9
  jb  insertLoop

...
```